# Stubbing Accounts._hashLoginToken in Meteor

Tags: meteor, jasmine, meteor-velocity

I am using [Jasmine](https://github.com/Sanjo/meteor-jasmine) BDD framework and would like to *server-unit-test* my method which returns user by his login token. This method calls `Account._hashLoginToken`, which needs to be stubbed, but when I try to do:

```
describe('method `getUserByToken`', function () {
  beforeEach(function () {
    Accounts._hashLoginToken = emptyFn;
    console.log(JSON.stringify(Accounts, null, 2));
    spyOn(Accounts, '_hashLoginToken').and.returnValue(true);
  });
};
```

it outputs to the server console:

```
{
  "urls": {},
  "emailTemplates": {
    "from": "Meteor Accounts <no-reply@meteor.com>",
    "siteName": "localhost:3000",
    "resetPassword": {},
    "verifyEmail": {},
    "enrollAccount": {}
  },
  "loginServiceConfiguration": {}
}
```

as you see `_hashLoginToken` is not included. [Html-reporter](https://github.com/meteor-velocity/html-reporter) in Velocity test framework shows error:

```
TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method '_hashLoginToken'
```

pointing to source code of my Meteor method.

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: Are you sure you've added in accounts-base?

Comment: It is *unit test*, so it should run in isolated environment anyway (without dependencies). According to [sanjo:jasmine package readme](https://github.com/Sanjo/meteor-jasmine/#server-unit-test-mode), all packages should be stubbed, but this method is probably missing.